# Grails Heroku deployment error

Tags: grails, heroku, deployment

When I try to deploy my Grails project to Heroku I got error

```
remote:        .
remote:        |Compiling 4 GSP files for package [databaseMigration]
remote:        ..
remote:        |Building WAR file
remote:        .................................................................
...................................................
remote:        |Precompiling Assets!
remote:        .Error
remote:        |
remote:        Error executing script War: java/nio/file/FileSystems (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
remote:  !     Failed to build app
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Grails app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to evening-spire-5280.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/evening-spire-5280.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/evening-spire-5280.git'
```

When create local war file everything is okay (`grails test war`, `grails dev war`)

**Update:**

As Burt Beckwit say NIO was added into JDK 7.

It's can be a problem OpenJDK 1.6 ?

```
remote: -----> Grails app detected
remote: -----> Grails 2.4.4 app detected
remote:        WARNING: The Grails buildpack is currently in Beta.
remote: -----> Installing OpenJDK 1.6...done
```

Comment: The `java.nio.file.FileSystems` class was added in JDK 7, but Heroku defaults to JDK 8, so that should work. Do you have a `system.properties` files configuring JDK 6?

Comment: Yes I have, set java.version=1.8.0_25

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and solved it downgrading the JDK to 1.7:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-java-version-to-an-existing-maven-app

Comment: In my file set java.runtime.version=1.8.0_25-b18, also by default 1.8 (on heroku), but when build start a see openjdk 1.6

Comment: Haver you updated the path as described on the link? Have you tried to set the version to 1.8 (instead of 1.8.0_25-b18)?